# index out of range error in character array

Tags: java, arrays, char, return

Please I am practiceing some java questions. I am trying to return a non repeating character in an integer. I have written my code and it works for some strings but some are bringing out index out of range error. I do no know where I have done something wrong
Here is my code:

```
class Challenge {
  static final int n = 256;
  static char[] count = new char[n];
  String str;
  
  static void charCounter( String str ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
      count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }
  }
  
  public static String firstNonRepeatingLetter( String str ) {
    charCounter(str);
    int pos = -1, i;
    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
      if(count[str.charAt(i)] == 1){
        pos = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return Character.toString(str.charAt(pos));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example input for which it throws an `index-out-of-range` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't considered what will happen in the case where all letters repeat, for example the string "ABBA".

You haven't specified full what the method is supposed to do in this case, but if returning an empty string is acceptable, you can change the return statement to:

```
if (pos < 0) return "";
return Character.toString(str.charAt(pos));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count[str.charAt(i)] == 1){
        pos = i;
        break;
      }
```

If your input String do not satisfies  `count[str.charAt(i)] == 1`. Then the pos value would remains -1 -> it would cause the error at return statement